# undefined reference in c++

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, undefined-reference

This is the error I have been getting.

```
-bash-4.1$ g++ strl.cpp -o -lc-
/tmp/ccRpiglh.o: In function `main':
strl.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `plusplus'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Hear is the source code for strl.cpp. This is a simple example that duplicates my problem.

```
strl.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "libc-.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  cout<<plusplus(5,2)<<'\n';
}
```

Here is the source for libc.cpp

```
libc.cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int plusplus(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}
```

Source for libc-.h

```
libc-.h 
#ifndef _SCANTYPE_H_
#define _SCANTYPE_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

  using namespace std;

  int plusplus(int a, int b);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif 

#endif
```

I am compiling with the following:

```
g++ -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libc-.so libc-.cpp
g++ strl.cpp -o -lc-
```

`g++ -Wall -shared -fPIC -o libc-.so libc-.cpp` compiles without error.

Why is function `plusplus` an undefined reference?

Thanks for any insight as to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

What is that 'using' in libc-.h for?
Anyway, it looks to me that you need to include this header in libc.cpp too. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1380926/2406949

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need `extern C` around the function definition? I bet the linker is trying to match the mangled c++ name with the unmangled C name.

And note that you are using C++ features (`using`), so the check for `#ifdef cplusplus` is redundant. If it's false your compiles will be failing.

Answer (score 0):

The reference to `plusplus()` is missing, because it's not provided. You are promising

```
`int plusplus(int a, int b);`
```

with `C` linkage in `libc-.h`, but are not keeping your promise in `libc.cpp`.
To fix the problem, change the latter file to

```
// libc.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "libc-.h"   // include proto-type which has C linkage

int plusplus(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}
```

Also, you should **never** do `using namespace std;` in a header file.